# Using django as an url resolving service

Tags: javascript, django, security, url

We have a web project that also has a REST interface for a mobile HTML5 application.

I would like to avoid both:

- Having to pass resolved urls as parameters to all my javascript classes on the web server
- Having to hardcode every url in the mobile app

I was thinking of using a fixed url, pointing to an ajax view, that is used to resolve url names (with parameters, also).

Aside from the -extra- request made to the server for those urls, is there a security concern with this approach?
Has someone stumbled upon a similar problem? Are there any methods to avoid this?

Thanks  in advance

Comment: rather than passing urls as a parameter to every js class why not just output the urls into a js file or the html template and have them as a global js var

Comment: @Anentropic well, that could be, but it sure makes the code more unreadable ... and it doesn't address the second concern

Comment: for not hardcoding urls in the mobile app you're going to have to have something like an 'urls' api endpoint. there's no security issue, assuming you're not relying on security by obscurity. but since you have to hardcode at least one url why not hardcode them all, saving the extra network trip. if the urls change its probably because the app changed ie you release a new version, can use permanent redirects on the server to keep earlier versions working.  not sure which option I'd choose myself, playing devil's advocate a bit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly doable. Currently using it with very good results